# Understanding the contents of the "continuation-token" request parameter of the "GET Bucket (List Objects) Version 2" command in S3 API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Does anyone know how to decode the contents provided by amazon S3 in this field of the response? It looks like a hashed string, but I need to understand what does it contain in it? Does it use some commonly used hashing?

Comment: Why do you want to try to decode it?

Comment: It's an opaque token.  It's not meant to be decoded.

Comment: I am working on an assignment where I ask user to select the number of object to be retrieved at once. It have used "NextMarker" present in the response to show the user exactly which object will be fetched in the next request. Now I have been asked to replace V1 listing with the V2. Since I can no longer use "NextMarker", the only option is to decode the "Continuation Token" to get the next object available. It will be a very small code change for me, If I know the contents of that token. I don't think its something confidential, as you can always see them in the web console.

Comment: To select the number of objects to be retrieved at once, set max-keys.  To see how many are returned, use key-count.  To convert from V1 to V2, the closest equivalent of "NextMarker" would be "StartAfter" on the request.  On the response, since V2 doesn't give you a handy response field like NextMarker, simply obtain this key from the last item in the response.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a hash, but the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects-v2.html) says it's obfuscated, maybe it's salted.

> NextContinuationToken is sent when isTruncated is true which means there are more keys in the bucket that can be listed. The next list requests to Amazon S3 can be continued with this NextContinuationToken. NextContinuationToken is obfuscated and is not a real key.

Example: 17z4MXisD8tDT/0+uf1UndaqeI3+K7vG8bso1NFBtbPq2gKRaS2Ax6
ioTgsamg0QOZt3V56dV4r0=