# AWS S3 ContinuationToken vs StartAfter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When listing objects in a bucket it seems the same paging functionality can be accomplished using either ContinuationToken or StartAfter. Consider the following boto3 code:

**ContinuationToken:**

```
objects = s3cli.list_objects_v2(Bucket='some-bucket', MaxKeys=20)
do_something(objects)
while (objects['IsTruncated']):
    objects = s3cli.list_objects_v2(Bucket='some-bucket', MaxKeys=20, ContinuationToken=objects['NextContinuationToken'])
    do_something(objects)
```

**StartAfter:**

```
objects = s3cli.list_objects_v2(Bucket='some-bucket', MaxKeys=20)
do_something(objects)
while (objects['IsTruncated']):
    objects = s3cli.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket, MaxKeys=20, StartAfter=objects['Contents'][-1]['Key'])
    do_something(objects)
```

Both of these loop through 20 objects at a time and take some action on them.
Are there specific benefits or pitfalls (efficiency, cost, etc) to using one over the other?
Is there something ContinuationToken can do (or is better at) that StartAfter cannot?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59203291/aws-s3-sdk-listobjectsv2-whats-difference-between-startafter-and-continuationto#:%7E:text=1%20Answer&text=StartAfter%20(string)%20%2D%2D%20StartAfter%20is,S3%20to%20start%20listing%20from.&text=ContinuationToken%20(string)%20%2D%2D%20ContinuationToken%20indicates,is%20not%20a%20real%20key.) is closely related.

Comment: Additional interesting information: [Understanding the contents of the “continuation-token” request parameter of the “GET Bucket (List Objects) Version 2” command in S3 API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43817082/174777)

Comment: One difference in usage is that `StartAfter` can be used to start _anywhere_ (eg start with objects that begin with `G`) while `ContinuationToken` only comes from previous requests. But, that doesn't address your question of relative advantages.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you can't start with objects *beginning* with G because if you specify StartAfter=G then the result won't include G itself. And if you try to be sneaky and set StartAfter=Fzzz then you *will* get G but you might also get Fzzzzzz, if it exists. Ideally the API would support both StartAfter and StartWith.